# Cannot view data returned by amfphp

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, amfphp

I've recently set up amfphp 2.2.1 on my win7pro (iis7.x) local host in the hope of getting away from XML between phph and Flash. I Followed the inital 'hello world' tut on amfphp website and everything was great.. it worked. My problem started when I tried querying a mySQL db.
my debug proxy says there is data being grabbed via amfphp/index.php (getAvailSvc/getBds) and it appears to be the data that I expected. When I try to view that data in Flash. When I try the simplest of functions

```
function handleResult(respond:Object):void{
    trace(respond);
    }
```

the trace give me [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]... etc

When I edit the trace to (respond.serverInfo.initialData) or my function to read the objects thus:

```
function handleResult(respond:Object):void{
        var h:Array = respond.serverInfo.initialData;
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < h.length; i++){
                trace (h[i][0]);
                }
    }
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at amf_fla::MainTimeline/handleResult()

I've searched and searched the web for amfphp tuts and guidance but most, if not all, the stuff I found is circa 6-7 years old and relates only to mysql_query stuff and amfphp 1.9-. If anyone can help I'd appreciate your support and aplogise in advance if its me just being stupid.

debug proxy output:
[image]

@Ariel Sommeria-Klein - raised here as suggested

Comment: You should probably consider switching to json instead. amf is incredibly hard to debug.

Comment: @Evert - Thanks for the response. my learning curver over the past 8 months has almost been vertical so forgive me if I reel at the suggestion of json, a technology for which I know absolutely nothing about. I was looking at amfphp because of the speed of native amf communication. If json does the same perhaps you might be able to post me some links to good json intro tuts... I'm no developer so please forgive my ignorance...

Comment: On json vs amf: amf is binary and therefore harder to debug just by reading it. With a proxy tool like Charles Proxy, I don't see any difference. But obviously I'm biased, I help maintain Amfphp.

Comment: @ArielSommeria-Klein I'm equally biased, as I maintained sabreamf. I have a pretty deep experience with it, and wrote the first open sourced AMF3 implementation using the help from the author of Charles. I'm convinced that there's only a small percentage that would benefit from using a proprietary, binary protocol. For the other 99%, a text based, well-supported, portable open standard is probably a wiser choice. Especially if you intend to move away from flash at some point in the future (as you should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object], because you are receiving an array of objects. In your AMF object, that would be "Content".
So if you try the following in your handleResult function:

```
trace(respond[0]);
```

you should see simply
[object Object]

and if you try the following:

```
trace(respond[0].name);
```

you should see 
Abbeydale Independent

Comment: Thanks, you're right and when I saw your response it was abundantly clear... I'd assumed (wrongly) that I needed (serverInfo.initialData) as per the tutorial I watched.. I watched it again this morning and there is no indication where 'serverInfo.initialData' comes from. Thanks so much.. now I'm trying to figure out how to run my full query and then get SELECT FOUND_ROWS() in the same method... Thanks again for your help